# MD Dialog Material Angular 2 wait for close

Tags: angular, angular-material, mddialog

I have a dialog with yes and no options(confirmation box). I want to wait till the user press yes or no button from dialog, but right now on button click, even before clicking the options in dialog box, console log prints initial/empty string.

HTML:

```xml
<button (click)="foo()"></button>
```

Component:

```typescript
selectedOption = '';

foo() {
  this.openDialog();
  console.log('selectedOption: ' + this.selectedOption); // Prints initial Value
  // hit the API if selectedOption is yes.
}

openDialog() {
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.selectedOption = result;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the way you wrote the code and the fact the `afterClosed` returns an Observable asynchronously.
After the call to 
      `this.openDialog();`
you are calling 
   `console.log(....);`
At this point the `selectedOption` is still empty because you initialized it at the top to an empty string.

Just move the console.log and the api logic to the the subscribe block:

```typescript
selectedOption = '';

foo() {
  this.openDialog();
}

openDialog() {
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.selectedOption = result;
    console.log('selectedOption: ' + this.selectedOption); // Prints 
    // hit the API if selectedOption is yes.
  });
 }
```